# How can I manage data use based on different periods of the day?

Tags: data-monitoring

I have a monthly pre-paid data plan with this detail:

- 1.2GB from 00am to 12pm (24 hours)
- 11GB between 0-9am (9 hours)

Is there a data manager app or other method that can monitor data usage with those hours parameters? I tried several apps but they're all using 24 hours parameter.

Comment: App recommendations are off-topic here, so I broadened the question slightly -- I'm sure you would be open to a method to do this within Settings if it exists, for example.  (Answerers might still suggest an app, but we want to help them focus on explaining how to do it rather than providing just a link with no detail.)